# Using php function inside mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm making a query that selects things by location - I need to make the selection in a way that it will check during the query if the product is in radius of 2 miles from the user location, the problem is that check is in another php function, and as much as I know I can't call php function with param from the database before the end of the query.

Thanks

The function that need to be used:

```
public static function vincentyGreatCircleDistance(
      $latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo, $earthRadius = 6371000)
    {
      // convert from degrees to radians
      $latFrom = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
      $lonFrom = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
      $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
      $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);

      $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;
      $a = pow(cos($latTo) * sin($lonDelta), 2) +
        pow(cos($latFrom) * sin($latTo) - sin($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * cos($lonDelta), 2);
      $b = sin($latFrom) * sin($latTo) + cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * cos($lonDelta);

      $angle = atan2(sqrt($a), $b);
      return $angle * $earthRadius;
    }
```

My query (without the location):

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `name` LIKE '%iphone%' OR `name` LIKE '%5s%'
```

What I want to do

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `name` LIKE '%iphone%' OR `name` LIKE '%5s%' AND vincentyGreatCircleDistance($lat, $long, `lat`,`long`) < 2
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible to use PHP method inside query like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for stored procedures - please see the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) on information on how to convert your function to a MySQL procedure.

Comment: Can you explain please how to make my php function to stored procedure?

Comment: Hey Itay, I won't be around for much of today, but I'll try to rewrite it for you later, if you haven't already found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There could be two possible ways I would suggest:

1) Try and see if you can convert your PHP function to a MySQL stored function. MySQL has its own library for mathematical operations. Once you have equivalent stored function you can directly call it like you call any other MySQL system function(even compared in WHERE clause).It would be treated simply like any other column.

2) If you couldn't able to convert your PHP function, 
    
You could use a tmp table for this. 
 Something like this:

> - CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `name`    LIKE '%iphone%' OR `name` LIKE '%5s%';
> - ALTER TABLE tmp ADD COLUMN vincentyGreatCircleDistance DOUBLE;
> - LOOP through the tmp result set

```
    while(tmp_resultset->row()){
       $r_lat=row->lat;
       $r_long=row->long;
       $vincentyGreatCircleDistance=vincentyGreatCircleDistance($lat, $long, $r_lat, $r_long);
       query_object("UPDATE SET vincentyGreatCircleDistance=IF(".$vincentyGreatCircleDistance.",".$vincentyGreatCircleDistance.",0) WHERE id=".row->id;
    }
```

> - SELECT * FROM tmp;

Hope this helps :)